# Golang: A map Interface, how to print key and value

Tags: go, interface

I get a map interface, like :

```
getUsersAppInfo := usersAppInfo.GetUsersAppInfo(getUserId)
```

then I print :

```
fmt.Println(getUsersAppInfo)
```

get this, like :

```
[map[appId:2 fcmServerKey:keyTestTest name:com.app]]
```

Ask : How to just print the value, like

```
appId value is 2 
name value is com.app 
fcmServerKey:keyTestTest value is keyTestTest
```

Comment: is []map[string]interface{}

Comment: Fundamental basics of  the language are covered in The Tour of Go which you might want  to work through once more. Note that in general there are no magic tricks in Go and if you want something to happen you have to write code making this happen.

Comment: @卓琮偉 answer to the question you just deleted. See https://play.golang.org/p/QEsYp1fn0wf.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The OP's comment on the question states that type of `getUsersAppInfo` is `[]map[string]interface{}`.

Loop over the slice of maps.  For each map, loop over the keys and values and print.

```
// loop over elements of slice
for _, m := range getUsersAppInfo {

    // m is a map[string]interface.
    // loop over keys and values in the map.
    for k, v := range m {
        fmt.Println(k, "value is", v)
    }
}
```

[Run this on the GoLang PlayGround](https://play.golang.org/p/H25g2nCsPQ-).

Comment: This example will still work, but I thought a slice of maps was more along the lines of `getUsersAppInfo := []map[string]interface{}{{"appId": 2, "fcmServerKey": "keyTestTest"}, {"name": "com.app","version": 2, "xyz": 3}}`

Comment: I thought your example was excellent. It works for more maps than the one map that was listed.

Answer (score 14):

I don't recommend to do this in production setup. But when I want to print out a map without too much code on my dev box, i print the JSON serialised version. This will be a crime to do in production.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    a := map[string]interface{}{"appId": 2, "fcmServerKey": "keyTestTest", "name": "com.app", "version": []int{1, 2, 3}, "xyz": 3}
    bs, _ := json.Marshal(a)
    fmt.Println(string(bs))
}
```

Output:

`{"appId":2,"fcmServerKey":"keyTestTest","name":"com.app","version":[1,2,3],"xyz":3}`

Comment: why is it a crime in prod? is it slow?

Comment: By far the easiest way to print out a map when you're just debugging stuff. Thanks.

Comment: @nanakondor because serialising is a costly operation. So if you were to do this, say on a high throughput request (1k> req/s) your instance will be spending quite some time in this operation itself who's sole purpose is for debugging.

Answer (score 4):

I'm afraid the only option is to iterate through the map:

```golang
getUsersAppInfo := map[string]interface{}{"foo": 3, "bar": "baz"}
for key, value := range getUsersAppInfo {
    fmt.Printf("%s value is %v\n", key, value)
}
```

Comment: I find a key word "reflect.ValueOf()".

Comment: Can I use it?   If it can.  How to use it?

Comment: you can, but you'll end up with the output you don't want. Because that's really what `fmt.Println` is calling behind the scene for a map. Use the code I gave you instead for the output you want.

Answer (score 0):

I have found this useful.

https://github.com/yakob-abada/go-api

```
import "github.com/k0kubun/pp/v3"

m := map[string]string{"foo": "bar", "hello": "world"}
pp.Print(m)
```

[image]